# Can Meshlab determine whether a point is inside a mesh

Tags: geometry, mesh, meshlab, vcg

Meshlab uses `vcglib` c++ library at its core. I was wondering if Meshlab can check if a point is inside a 3D mesh (polyhedron). I found [an article](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-remove-internal-faces-with.html) which explains a possible way to determine an internal face. However, the proposed method colors vertices based on ambient occlusion, which is dependent on the camera view, and therefore is limited.

Is Meshlab able to use ray casting and get an information for determining if a point is an interior point or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambient occlusion is not viewpoint dependent - it's a calculation of the visibility from all ambient lighting, which is in every direction.

Meshlab can do this via

```
Filters > Color Creation and Processing > Ambient occlusion (per vertex or per facet)
```

Comment: To clarify, after running the ambient occlusion filter, you can then go to filters > selection > select by face/vertex quality in order to select the facets/vertices with low/high occlusion